# How to redirect output of a program to a ZIP file?

Tags: logs, pipe, zip

I am running a script which is collecting a log of a server. I need to redirect this logs to a ZIP file. Right now I am collecting data into text file.

How can I redirect it directly to ZIP?

Comment: Is gzip acceptable instead of zip?

Comment: Why not simply collecting your log files in a folder and zip that folder at the end?

Comment: You might want to add the relevant parts of your script in your question.

Comment: Question seems perfectly clear enough to me.

Comment: Easy solution: create a named pipe (`mkfifo`), run `zip` with `-FI` arguments on it, dump all the logs into named pipe.

Answer (score 11):

Using `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009`, I was able to do this:

```
$ date | zip jeff.zip -
$ unzip -l jeff.zip
Archive:  jeff.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       29  01-21-2016 13:02   -
---------                     -------
       29                     1 file
$ unzip -p jeff.zip | cat
Thu Jan 21 13:02:31 EST 2016
$ unzip -p jeff.zip > newfilename.here
```

This uses `date` as a substitute for your script that collects the log file, to stdout presumably; it sends that stdout to zip, telling it to take its input from stdin instead of a filename (with `-`). The contents of the zip file aren't named anything recognizable, but the data is there.

Answer (score 7):

You could pipe direct to `gzip`, then redirect compressed data to a file:

```
echo "my not compacted data" | gzip > compact.gz
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. The question is about ZIP and not GZIP.

Comment: This is what you should do if `.zip` is not a strict requirement, and piping into any common compressor is fine.