# Any work-around to pipe zip files?

Tags: pipe, backup, mysql, zip, stdout

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and Bash. I know that it's not possible to **directly** pipe data into `zip`.

For example, if you host websites on Apache/Nginx webserver, this command set would fail after filling in the password:

```
drt="/var/www/html"
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip"
```

What will be your workaround if you really desire the end file to be a zip file?

Comment: A workaround would be to use `gzip`, `bzip2`, or even `xz` instead of `zip`, and accept that Unix and Windows are different platforms with different software capabilities.

Comment: hahaha, that's a comment with a funny part. I accept that, but workarounds can be done, sometimes, as you know.

Comment: Actually, I'm really quite serious. You're backing up MySQL databases. Why not use native compression tools?

Comment: I know you are. I don't know gzip and I'm not sure I won't have problems uploading these to MySQL and MySQL like databases. It's not likely I'll have any problems but I'm not sure and I would prefer to stay with Zip that I know better, there is a small enough workaround, though I'm open to `gzip` or anything working slightly with these databases anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use `zip`, you can use [Jeff Schaller’s trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256830/86440):

```
drt="/var/www/html"
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" -
```

This will create a ZIP file containing a file named `-` whose contents are the database dump. This is mentioned in the `zip` manpage:

> `zip` also accepts a single dash ("-") as the name of a file to be compressed, in which case it will read  the  file  from  standard
>          input, allowing zip to take input from another program. For example:
>
> ```
> tar cf - . | zip backup -
> ```

You could also use `/dev/stdin` instead:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip -FI "$drt/db-$date.zip" /dev/stdin
```

This would result in an archive containing a file named `dev/stdin` which might be harder to handle properly. `-` is a common short-hand to tell programs to use standard input or output; it’s not something that the shell handles, it has to be supported by each individual program.

In both cases you’d probably want to use `funzip` to extract the data; it extracts the first member of an archive to its standard output.

Comment: .. or `unzip -p` and redirect

Comment: I must say I'm still confused about why it must be a named pipe and not a regular pipe, I mean, why would the `zip` utility developers care if use an anonymous or a named pipe. Maybe there isn't a clear answer to that question.

Comment: So instead having say `mysql.sql` inside the end zip I'll have `-` or `dev/stdin` with the sql data. That's a tiny bit depressing but I might need to eat more non depressing foods like Chocolate, to handle that.

Comment: It *can* be a regular pipe, if you use a hyphen.

Comment: I didn't figure it out from the answer. :\ my apologies.

Comment: I realise for some reason the `-` in `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" -` is hard to see, but I don’t understand what makes you think you need a named pipe there — “named pipe” isn’t mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I thought that because of the `-FI` argument which I understood from `man zip` to represent a FIFO.

Comment: Notice that `-FI` is only used for `/dev/stdin`, not for `-`. Details matter ;-).

Comment: Indeed details matter. Ii wasn't clear to me at start (likely I misread as I was being hard to concentrate from problems I must get more well from). Now I know this and commented this to myself. When I use just an anonymous pipe and a hyphen, I don't use `-FI`. Anyway, seems I have trouble running a function containing this command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437640/hyphen-ignored-in-the-end-of-a-piped-command-nested-inside-a-function

Answer (score 9):

If you are open to alternative compression tools, try this almost identical alternative.

```
drt="/var/www/html"
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | gzip >"$drt/db-$date.gz"
```

If you prefer you can substitute `gzip` with `bzip2` or `xz`, and the typical extension from `gz` to `bz2` or `xz`.

Comment: `xz` is often better than `bzip2` these days.  Both are slow to compress, but `xz` decompresses faster and often gets a better compression ratio (https://tukaani.org/xz/ claims 15% better than bzip2)  It uses LZMA2 like 7-zip.

Comment: @Peter ah yes. I'd mentioned it in my original comment (under the question) but omitted to include it here. Good reminder, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* prefer a zip file over using `gzip` or `tar`:

```
drt="/var/www/html"
scratch="$(mktemp)"
if mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > "$scratch"; then
  zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" "$scratch"
fi
rm -f  "$scratch"
```

Optionally, you can use a temporary directory to have a more useful filename:

```
drt="/var/www/html"
scratchdir="$(mktemp -d)"
if mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > "${scratchdir}/db-${date}.sql"; then
  zip -j "$drt/db-$date.zip" "${scratchdir}/db-${date}.sql"
fi
rm -rf "$scratchdir"
```

Comment: The name scratch is a must here?

Comment: No, that's just my default stand-in variable name for a "scratch file", i. e. one written to and discarded after use.  `mktemp` creates a new file with a _random_ name, so you need to capture that name to a variable if you want to actually do anything to it with a script.  Helpfully, it outputs the path to the created file, which is why varname="$(mktemp)" works.

Comment: `mktemp` is guaranteed to create a new file which does not already exist.  Sanity checking for existing procedural file names are left as an exercise for the OP as they are beyond the scope of the question at hand.

Comment: My only suggestion here would be to chain the mysqldump, zip, and rm together with `&&`

Comment: The scratch file would need to be removed either way, but I have added a sanity check to only create the archive if `mysqldump` succeeds.  As to the complaint about renaming the scratch file, keep in mind that using a defined name was a retrofit of the earlier example in case the filename actually _matters_.