# Hyphen (-) ignored in the end of a piped command nested inside a function?

Tags: bash, zip, syntax, bash-functions

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) with Bash 4.3.48(1).

Based on the answer of Stephen Kitt [in this session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436849/any-work-around-to-pipe-zip-files), I tried run the following command as part of a function named `imb()`:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" -
```

I sourced the file in which the `imb()` function sits:

```
source ~/functions.sh
```

### The function

```
imb() {
    drt="/var/www/html"
    date="$(date +\%F-\%T)"
    mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" - # Note the hyphen before this comment;
    zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*"
    rm -f "$drt/db-$date.zip"
}
```

### My problem

Calling the function fails with the `zip` error:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/html/db-2018-04-13-22:27:47.zip)
```

This seems to happen because the hyphen ignored somehow; I assume that from a look in:

```
type -a imb
```

which outputs:

```
imb is a function

imb () {
    date="$(date +\%F-\%T)";
    mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip";
    zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*";
    rm -f "$drt/db-$date.zip" 
}
```

I noted the missing hyphen here.

### My question

Why does the function fails / why does Bash allegedly ignores the hyphen?

Comment: Tested `imb` on *bash v4.4-ubuntu1*, and the hyphen doesn't vanish from the output of `type -a imb`.

Comment: Still driver, sorry, I only sourced the file containing it. I edited to show how. No export as I didn't call it from another function, but directly through Bash.

Comment: Can you edit in 1) the value of `$IFS` (use `printf %s "$IFS" | hexdump -C`) and 2) the output of `sed -ne '/imb/,/}/p' functions.sh`?

Comment: Not related to the problem but the backslashes in `date +\%F-\%T` are useless.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce; I copy-pasted the definition from your question. I suspect Michael's on the right track, looking for something "off" in your local environment or file.

Comment: Having `IFS=-` will not make the dash disappear. I believe you may have an old version of the function in your environment. Do `unset -f imb` and source the file again.

Comment: @Kusalananda now I didn't have the error, and some time passed between creating a sql and a zip, and I also got verbose creation of a zip of all `/var/www/html/` so it should be an answer; though, no zip was created.

Comment: @HaukeLaging did these became useless in a particular Bash version or is it from just recently? (A web development teacher showed it to me once).

Comment: `\%` has always been useless because `%` is not a special char for the shell.

Comment: @user9303970 The one place you need `\%` is in a crontab. `%` is not a special character in bash, but it is one for cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an old version of the function in your environment, and hadn't re-sourced the file after you edited it to add the missing `-`.

When you did re-source the file, or restart your shell, you obtained the corrected version of the function that you saw in the file. That version works.

That's really all there is to it; there's nothing interesting to explain here. It's a fairly common situation that the environment ends up out of sync with the files that set it up and it leads to momentary confusion often, but it's easily resolved as it was in this case.