# Repeatedly creating files named /dev/stdin can be dangerous?

Tags: bash, stdin

In the third edition of "Learning the Bash shell" by Newham and Rosenblatt it is written in page 15 as a comment:

> if a particular UNIX utility doesn't accept standard input when you
>   leave out the filename argument, try using a dash (0) as the argument.
>   Some NIX systems provide standard input as a file so you could try
>   providing the file /dev/stdin as the input file argumnet.

The last sentence isn't clear to me - what's the meaning of "provide standard input as a file"?

Isn't it dangerous to "repeatedly" create files named `/dev/stdin` in a system (I personally use Ubuntu 16.04).

BTW I came across a similar case in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436849/any-work-around-to-pipe-zip-files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn’t about creating `/dev/stdin`, it’s about using it: you specify `/dev/stdin` as the file to be used with whatever command doesn’t support standard input by default (or using `-`), to make it use its standard input anyway.

Thus

```
cat
cat -
cat /dev/stdin
```

all make `cat` read from its standard input (albeit in a slightly different way when using `/dev/stdin`, with a different file descriptor, which means it’s not equivalent in all cases). I’m not *creating* `/dev/stdin`, I’m using the pre-existing device node as an argument to `cat`.

Comment: Does accessing `/dev/stdin` like this with `bash` (specifically) actually use the device in `/dev` or does it use `bash`'s own built-in/simulated device?

Comment: @Kusalananda the Bash manual says “If the operating system on which Bash is running provides these special files, bash will use them; otherwise it will emulate them internally with the behavior described below.” so if there is a node in `/dev` Bash uses that.

Comment: I was just about to go look at the source code. Reading the manual is cheating ;-)   Thanks.

Comment: They're all equivalent except on Linux (and possibly Cygwin), where `/dev/stdin` is a link to the file opened on stdin. Opening it will not give you the same open file description as on stdin (contrary to on other systems). On Linux, opening `/dev/stdin` won't work when stdin is a socket (try `echo foo | cat /dev/stdin` in ksh93 for instance), could give you the other end of a pipe. For seekable files (like regular files), it would open  the file at the beginning (try `(head > /dev/null; cat /dev/stdin) < /etc/passwd` and compare with `cat` or `cat -` for instance).

Comment: @Kusalananda, in the case of `cat /dev/stdin`, since `cat` is not a shell builtin in `bash`, `bash` cannot "emulate" anything. It just passes `/dev/stdin` as argument to `cat`. It's only in the target of redirections that `bash` may emulate those.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Only for built-ins and redirections then. I get it.

Comment: @StephenKitt Because it happens for `cat` without passing `-` or `/dev/stdin` I assume that for `cat` it is default.

Comment: What may be a better example than `cat`?

Comment: @user9303970 One example could be in a script where you run a utility that reads from a file whose  filename is in a variable, but you want it to read from standard input. You then specify /dev/stdin as the filename instead.

Comment: I totally miss the meaning of that comment, sadly, dear @Kusalananda

Comment: @user9303970 the default is what `cat` (or anything else) does in the absence of anything more specific; so `-` and `/dev/stdin` are *not* ignored.